# JQuery change text of paragraph which contains image

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html

```
<p id="logo400_120_spinner"><img src="/global/img/spinner.gif"></p>
```

I use jquery to try to set the text to Loading or removing depending on circumstance but I am just getting the text and losing the spinner image. I would like the spinner to be present with text on the right hand side

Here is the jquery I use

```
 $("#logo400_120_spinner").text('Loading');
 $("#logo400_120_spinner").show();
```

The spinner image disappears with the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.html()` to change the inner HTML instead of just the plaintext so you can use an `img` tag

To show:

```
 $("#logo400_120_spinner").html('<img src="/global/img/spinner.gif">Loading');
 $("#logo400_120_spinner").show();
```

To get rid of the loading text:

```
$("#logo400_120_spinner").html('<img src="/global/img/spinner.gif">');
```

Another option is just to put the "Loading" text into a span and just show and hide that span with JQuery.

Comment: makes no difference, same as with using .text()

Answer (score 0):

Append the text you want to the element.

```
$("#logo400_120_spinner").append('Loading');
```

If you want to position it properly, you might want to consider adding an element with a class, or a block-level element: -

```
$("#logo400_120_spinner").append('<p class="myCustomClass">Loading...</p>');
```

Text removed by

```
$("#logo400_120_spinner .myCustomClass").remove();
```